# How can I update the key comparing two dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, substring

I have two dictionary as below

```
dict_1 = {exam : student, test: faculty}
dict_2 = {s1: [student as s, advisor as a, teacher as t], s2 : [faculty as fac, marks as m]}
```

I want to see if partial value of dict_1 exists in dict_2 values then update the key of dict_2 with dict_1 key,  output will look like this

```
dict_2 = {exam: [student as s, advisor as a, teacher as t], test : [faculty as fac, marks as m]}
```

Comment: @AndrejKesely Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the keys and values in lists are strings:

```py
dict_1 = {"exam": "student", "test": "faculty"}
dict_2 = {
    "s1": ["student as s", "advisor as a", "teacher as t"],
    "s2": ["faculty as fac", "marks as m"],
}

out = {}
for k, v in dict_1.items():
    for kk, vv in dict_2.items():
        if any(v in vvv for vvv in vv):
            out[k] = vv
            break

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "exam": ["student as s", "advisor as a", "teacher as t"],
    "test": ["faculty as fac", "marks as m"],
}
```